# Mongoose pagination wont show number of pages

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pagination

I am trying to build pagination with mongoose-paginate but it wont show number of pages or pages...

Route.js

```
// View users
router.get("/show", function (req, res, next) {

    var query = {};
    var options = {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 10
    };

    User.paginate(query, options).then(function (result) {
        return res.render("../modules/users/views/userList", {
            layout: 'cmsLayout',
            users: result.docs,
            page: parseInt(result.page),
            pages: parseInt(result.pages)
        });
    });
});
```

Handlebars

```
 {{#each pages}}
     <h1>{{this}}</h1>
 {{/each}}
```

// Result is NOTHING

```
  <h2>{{pages}}</h2>
```

// Result is NaN

I am looking for any advice how to show page numbers like 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The [Document](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate#readme) of `mongoose-paginate`**

Promise fulfilled with object having properties:

- docs {Array} - Array of documents
- total {Number} - Total number of documents in collection that match a query
- limit {Number} - Limit that was used
- [page] {Number} - **Only if specified** or default page/offset values were used
- [pages] {Number} - **Only if page specified** or default page/offset values were used
- [offset] {Number} - **Only if specified** or default page/offset values were used

It seems that **`Only if`** counts here.

---

```
//Skip 20 documents and return 10 documents
Model.paginate({}, { page: 3, limit: 10 }).then(function(result) {
    // result.docs
    // result.total
    // result.limit - 10
    // result.page - 3
    // result.pages
});
```

So we can do like this.

- Here we use `page`. `offset` requires us to compute manually, which sucks here.
- Mostly, we don't need to parse anything. The author of the package has wrapped for you.

---

```
router.get("/show", function (req, res, next) {
    var query = {};
    var options = { page: 1, limit: 10 };

    User.paginate(query, options).then(function (result) {
        return res.render("../modules/users/views/userList", {
            layout: "cmsLayout",
            users: result.docs,
            page: result.page, // The page num which equals 1.
            size: result.limit, // The page size which equals 10.
            pages: result.pages // It seems like the total page num. Not sure.
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any other information you haven't show here?